# EF Core A second operation was started on this context.... with only one thread in single method

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I have a test in C# that test a Stored Procedure(SP) in a SQL server database.

I have written the test in MSTest.
The test emulates three months of usage of the SP. The SP returns a list of values that should be exported to an external recipient by doing some convoluted selects.
The system uses EF Core to communicate with the database.

This all works fine, except I frequently get the error:
A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed.
This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.

The problem I have is that there is only one thread and no async involved. All code is run in a single method.

So I have no idea where to begin to look for multiple usage of the context.
From what I can see it seems that EFC does not complete the previous operation before it let my code continue.

It is no always the same code or even the same method that fail. Sometimes it is the Save method sometimes FromRawSql.
Sometimes it fail in the beginning of the test sometimes at the end.
But mostly it works as expected.

What is extra disturbing is that most of the code is production code. Making me worry that we might get intermittent error in production.

The pseudo code would look something like this.

1. Init the test, create a context and setup the database through migration.
2. Add base data to the database through EFC and Save.
3. Check the export through calling FromRawSql getting the values from the SP.
4. Assert the result of the call to the SP.
5. Modify the values in the db through EFC and Save.
6. Check the export through calling FromRawSql getting the values from the SP.
7. Assert the result of the call to the SP.
8. Repeat step 5 – 7 until done.

This will frequently fail at step 5 or 6 at random iteration.

Sense I have no idea where to start with this any idea is appreciated.

Comment: You didn't post any code or relevant information. The exception text means you tried to use the same DbContext instance from multiple threads, which is simply wrong. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. Its job is to track all changes and *persist all of them in a single transaction* when `SaveChanges` is called. It's meant to be short-lived, which is why all samples and examples show creating it in a `using` block, or defined as a `Scoped` dependency. DbContext doesn't even open a connection until it needs to either read data or save changes, and closes it afterwards

Comment: `All code is run in a single method.` please post your code. Where is the DbContext generated and stored ? If it was created in a `using` block in the method there would be no issue. Is it stored in a field? A static field perhaps? As a test fixture available to multiple test instances? Does your test code forget to `await` some async method which keeps running even after the test completes?

Comment: Check how your test is being provided with an instance of your DbContext. Many test runners will run tests in parallel and if they aren't configured to inject/instantiate a DbContext per test then multiple tests could end up using the same Context leading to intermittent errors when they happen to overlap access and the DbContext detects it.